# Can't compile cwm recovery

Tags: android, c, compilation, cyanogenmod

Hi all I'm translating cwm recovery. I downloaded cm source. But when i enter this command :

make -j4 recoveryimage

i get too many errors and compilation fails :

```
    jale@jale-PC:~/android$ make -j4 recoveryimage
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.4.2
CM_VERSION=
TARGET_PRODUCT=full
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.8.0-19-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-13.04-raring
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=KOT49H
OUT_DIR=/home/jale/android/out
============================================
/home/jale/android/out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS/SignatureTest_intermediates
find: “src”: No file or directory
grep: /build/target/board/generic/recovery.fstab: No file or directory
No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE generic
build/core/tasks/kernel.mk:91: **********************************************************
build/core/tasks/kernel.mk:92: * Kernel source found, but no configuration was defined  *
build/core/tasks/kernel.mk:93: * Please add the TARGET_KERNEL_CONFIG variable to your   *
build/core/tasks/kernel.mk:94: * BoardConfig.mk file                                    *
build/core/tasks/kernel.mk:95: **********************************************************
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld: error: /home/jale/android/out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/crtbrand.o: file is empty
make: *** [/home/jale/android/out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/crtbegin_static.o] Hata 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished operations....
target thumb C++: libc <= bionic/libc/bionic/pthread_debug.cpp
target thumb C++: libc <= bionic/libc/bionic/libc_init_dynamic.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option '-std=gnu99' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: command line option '-std=gnu99' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
bionic/libc/bionic/libc_init_dynamic.cpp:95:17: warning: unused parameter 'onexit' [-Wunused-parameter]
bionic/libc/bionic/pthread_debug.cpp:545:13: warning: 'void hashmap_removeEntry(HashTable*, HashEntry*)' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
jale@jale-PC:~/android$
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need follow the instructions to select device want to build source for and build kernel first.